# Highlight Element on Chrome like in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a way to highlight and keep highlighted an element in chrome, like it's in firefox?

It's often, that I have to keep an element highlighted, when I manipulate the styles.

[Keep Element highlighted in Firefox Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqCbZ.png)

Comment: Simply hover the mouse over the selector.

Comment: thats the point: i dont want to keep the mouse on the selector, and sometimes keep one selected an manipulate an other element

Comment: Well that's the only method. You can use the keyboard to manipulate the other element.

Comment: yes, this is how i do it for now but it's not comfortable and handy. i hoped there is something in the dev-tools plugins or something…